# join two overlapping dataframes vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update `df1` with `df2`:

> 1. add new rows from `df2` to `df1`
> 2. update existing rows (if row index exist)

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,4]], index=[1,2], columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[3,2]], index=[3,2], columns=['a','b'])
```

The expected result should be

```py
    a   b
1   1   3
2   2   3
3   1   0
```

but

```py
df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates(keep='last') # drop_duplicates has no effect
```

gives a simple vertical stack

```py
    a   b
1   1   3
2   2   4
3   1   0
2   2   3
```

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

gives the same values and destroys the row index

```py
    a   b
0   1   3
1   2   4
2   1   0
3   2   3
```

```py
df1.join(df2)
df1.loc[df2.index] = df1.values
```

raise error

Comment: So the logic is you want to overwrite the index 2 row in the first df with the index 2 row in the second df?

Comment: @PaulBrennan yes. and also add the index 3 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df = df1.append(df2)
new_df = new_df[~new_df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Comment: looks good. thanks. I'm still surprised pandas haven't provided a builtin function for such updating